# Understanding getter and setter routine

Tags: objective-c

I'm in process of reading Obj-C book and I'm not fully understand whats going on.

There is code of my app in `main.m` function:

```
    Rectangle *myRect = [[Rectangle alloc]init];

    XYPoint *myPoint = [[XYPoint alloc]init];

    [myPoint setX:100 andY:200];

    myRect.origin = myPoint;

    XYPoint *theOrigin = [myRect origin];

    [theOrigin setX:200];
    [theOrigin setY:300];

    NSLog(@"Test %i and %i", theOrigin.x, theOrigin.y);

    NSLog(@"Origin at (%i, %i)", myRect.origin.x, myRect.origin.y);
```

You see, i insert following code:

```
 XYPoint *theOrigin = [myRect origin];

        [theOrigin setX:200];
        [theOrigin setY:300];
```

I made it for purpose, actually, i didn't want that values to be changed. In Rectangle.m file i modified setter method as follow:

```
-(void)setOrigin:(XYPoint *)pt{ 
    if (!origin){  
        origin = [[XYPoint alloc]init];
        origin.x = pt.x;
        origin.y = pt.y;
    }
}
```

So, logic is, when origin is not zero, it can't be changed (if i understand correct). But NSLog still output values of 200 and 300, therefore, it changed after first declaration?

When try to modify my XYPoint class like this:

```
[myPoint setX:50 andY:50];
NSLog(@"Origin at (%i, %i)", myRect.origin.x, myRect.origin.y);
```

I got same output. Its confusing.

I try to modify getter method like follow (to create a copy and return copy instead):

```
-(XYPoint*)origin{

    if (origin){
        XYPoint *copy = [[XYPoint alloc]init];
        copy = origin;
        NSLog(@"Copy will be returned");
        return copy;
    }   else {
        return  origin;
    }
}
```

But it still appears that problem here, and output the same, values keep changing. How to modify getter method to prevent this happening?

Why is that happen? How to prevent this?
Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined your setter for `origin` property such that you cannot change it once you set it. But you've defined `XYPoint` such that it's a mutable class (i.e. you can change the `x` and `y` values). So, when you return `theOrigin` of `[myRect origin]`, you are still able to change its values.

---

Personally, I would step back from this interface. I am not a fan of a class interface that suggests that you can set some property when you really cannot. I'm also not crazy about the fact that `setOrigin` is employing something akin to `copy` memory semantics, but you haven't shared a property definition that makes that intent explicit.

But going back to what I presume was the intent to not let the `origin` change once it's been set, I'd rather just see you set these properties when the objects are instantiated, but then leave them as `readonly` so you can be confident that they won't be mutated on you. The end result is a set of classes that are entirely intuitive.

Thus:

```
@interface XYPoint : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGFloat x;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGFloat y;

- (instancetype)initWithX:(CGFloat)x y:(CGFloat)y;

@end
```

Where

```
@implementation XYPoint

- (instancetype)initWithX:(CGFloat)x y:(CGFloat)y {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Likewise, I'd be inclined to make the `origin` of `Rectangle` to be `readonly`.

```
@interface Rectangle : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly) XYPoint *origin;

- (instancetype)initWithOrigin:(XYPoint *)origin;

@end
```

Where

```
@implementation Rectangle

- (instancetype)initWithOrigin:(XYPoint *)origin {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _origin = origin;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Then once you create your `XYPoint` and `Rectangle` objects, you can be confident that the properties will not mutate.

```
XYPoint *origin = [[XYPoint alloc] initWithX:100 y:200];
Rectangle *rect = [[Rectangle alloc] initWithOrigin:origin];
```

There are other approaches, but I really don't like your approach of a setter that won't set the value. You can do that, but it's unintuitive. As a developer, you expect that when you set a property, that property actually changes.

Comment: Thank you Rob, but why when i add [myPoint setX:50 andY:50]; code nothing changed? NSLog(@"Origin at (%i, %i)", myRect.origin.x, myRect.origin.y); output the same values, and in this case i try to modify mutable class myPoint.

Comment: In your `myRect.origin = myPoint;` is calling a setter, `setOrigin`, that isn't really using `myPoint`, but rather instantiates a new `XYPoint` and sets it's `x` and `y` (behaving like a property with `copy` memory semantics, even though it wasn't declared as such). So subsequent attempts to change `myPoint` won't affect the new `XYPoint` that `setOrigin` created. But, once you retrieve a reference to this object by calling the rectangle's `origin` getter, you _are_ allowing the `x` and `y` to be mutated.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answers, now picture in my mind is clear, and i also now get the meaning of readonly property. Still, one more thing, i wish to know how to modify existing getter method to prevent changing values of myRect.origin. Could you please write some tips? Take a look at modified question at bottom. Thanks

Comment: The expectation of any developer is generally that if you're returning a mutable object, that mutating it will change the property that it originally referenced. If you're going to deviate from that, make it brutally explicit (e.g. `NSURLSessionTask` is supplied a "request" when you you create it, but if you inquire later, it's called `originalRequest`, to make it clear that you cannot change the request after it has already started).

Comment: Furthermore, if you have a `readwrite` property, it is assumed that unless the property bears the `copy` memory semantics, that if you mutate the object that you passed to the property's setter, that you're mutating that property which is pointing to the same object.

Comment: Bottom line, avoid writing custom setters or getters that do not conform well established patterns and conventions. You'll just make things really, really confusing if you violate these well established rules. You want to be able to return to this code at some point in the future, and be able to infer what is going on by just looking at the public interface (rather than having to remember all these non-standard implementation details.

Comment: I just following task author of the book ask me to do, point of this task is not practical usage of that knowledge, but to understand concept and programming language.